Impresión de un mensaje error en Java
es algo básico, lo que pasa es que debo imprimir un mensaje de error al mostrar palabras reservadas en un analizador léxico o lexer pero solo me está mostrando el error como tal y no el texto que yo le estoy declarando en el String.
private void imprimirMensajeError() {
    System.out.println("El error encontrado es: " + errores);
}

String errores[][] = {
    {"500", " Se esperaba un digito "},
    {"501", " Se esperaba un = "},
    {"502", " Se esperaba un > "},
    {"503", " Se esperaba una comilla "},
    {"504", " Se esperaba un ) "},
    {"505", " Se esperaba un / "},
    {"506", " Se esperaba un = "}
};

En lugar de mostrarme el contenido del String simplemente me muestra el codigo del error, ejemplo:
El error encontrado es: [[Ljava.lang.String;@9b54596

Y se repite varias veces

Es funcionamiento correcto.
Estas imprimiendo el array de arrays completo.
La representación en String de un array de arrays es como Object
Tienes que añadir errores[codError] para obtener el string asociado. Hay que pasar una clave para obtener valores asociados
